# Submenu Dropdown Query

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

Need to add multiple dropdown menus like:

```
1. Products
  1.1 Products Menu
    1.1.1 Submenu One
    1.1.2 Submenu Two
  1.2 test

2. Quality
```

Have tried with different combinations of dropdown classes and submenu wrapper. Require assistance

```
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Our Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <!-- submenu-wrapper -->
    <div class="submenu-wrapper submenu-wrapper-topbottom">
        <div class="submenu-inner  submenu-inner-topbottom">
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Cable Management System <b class="caret"></b></a></li>


                <li><a href="#">Facade, Concrete & Blockworks Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Architectural & Industrial Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /submenu-wrapper -->
</li>
```

Expected Output

```
1. Products
  1.1 Cable Management System
    1.1.1 Submenu One
    1.1.2 Submenu Two

  1.2 Facade

  1.3 Architecture
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar to your query using HTML 5 like this. Please feel free to comment or suggest if you need any more details.

```
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Products
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li class="dropdown-submenu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="####">Products Menu</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a [routerLink]="['####']">Submenu One</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown-item"><a [routerLink]="['####']">Submenu Two</a></li>


            </ul>
          </li>
         <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#">Test</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Thanks,
Prithwi P C

Comment: Hi Nirmal, please add div tags.

Comment: Addition of div tags will completely mess the menus